# Issue configuring hibernate in my Spring Application

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I was configuring hibernate on my Spring application and get following errors on my servlet-context file.

What have I messed up with the xml files??

**Error is as follows:**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Line 38 in XML document from ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 38; columnNumber: 109;
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'bean'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":import,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":alias,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":bean,
>   WC[##other:"http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"],
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans":beans}' is expected.

**My Servlet-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans:beans xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task
http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing 
    infrastructure -->

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
    up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<!-- <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/images/" /> -->

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources 
    in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:import resource="classpath:/WEB-INF/controllers.xml" />
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" >
    </bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}">
</bean>


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

You start off using the namespace prefix

```
<beans:bean...
```

and

```
<beans:property...
```

but then you stop

```
<bean...
```

and

```
<property...
```

Why? Any element that is part of the `beans` namespace needs to be prefixed with `beans`.

Alternatively, make `beans` your [default namespace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace) so that you don't have to prefix all the elements that belong to it.